# How to add a class to select_tag in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having difficulty adding a class tag to this:

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag(:school_or_org, "Are you a school or a non-profit organization?") %> 
    <%= select_tag(:school_or_org, options_for_select([ ['school', "school"], ['non-profit', "non-profit"] ]))  %> 
  </div>
```

This is what I've tried, among others:

```
      <div class="field">
         <%= label_tag(:school_or_org, "Are you a school or a non-profit organization?") %> 
         <%= select_tag(:school_or_org, options_for_select([ ['school', "school"], ['non-profit', "non-profit"], {:class => 'form-control'} ]))  %> 
     </div>
```

When I check it via firefbug, I don' see the class information, so clearly it's not being added.

How do I get it added so it shows up in the form?

Merci

**Edit One**

Do you mean like this:

```
 <%= select_tag(:school_or_org, options_for_select([ ['school', "school"], ['non-profit', "non-profit"]] ), {:class => 'form-control'})  %>
```

It didn't work.

Just for reference, this is what I'm trying to have the select box look like: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms (look at Selects section). That's where I got 'form-control' from.

Comment: Do you want the class to be added to the select box or the select options?

Comment: @patrickmcgraw, to select box, i think, for now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using [the `select` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), you need an empty options hash followed by your html options like so:

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

With your example, that would look like this:

```
<%= select(:school_or_org, options_for_select([ ['school', "school"], ['non-profit', "non-profit"]] ), {}, {:class => 'form-control'})  %>
```

If you are using [the `select_tag` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag), you can add in the hash at the end as part of the options hash:

```
 select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})
```

This works because any options that are not recognised are passed in as standard HTML attributes.

With your example , that would look like this:

```
<%= select_tag(:school_or_org, options_for_select([ ['school', "school"], ['non-profit', "non-profit"]] ), {:class => 'form-control'})  %>
```

Comment: this is what I get when I copy your answer: "wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)" .... and i didn't modify anything else. why is it coming up with that answer?

Comment: My apologies, I had was thinking about the `select` helper, not the `select_tag` helper. I have modified my answer with an explanation of the difference (with references). Either of these should now work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the class on the select box itself, then you have a parenthesis nesting error happening here. The `{:class => 'form-control'}` snippet needs to be outside of the parens for the `options_for_select` call.

If you want the class to be applied to the options then each array element needs the class declaration like so: `['non-profit', "non-profit", {:class => 'form-control'}]`

Comment: i've updated my post with how I did it. it still didn't work. what did i do wrong?