# Rails 5: enum from select not saved on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I'm trying to update/save enum in database, however **seems it is not passing as param correctly**. 
On Update paramters are passed, except "role" (used as enum) which seems to be outside of hash (3rd line):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5mjLbYZH6tJWOympfEApF2EwbR/Nk4cQFvqtCiXhL3hOIs+yOQGbZUaIFqO42aMyUWr3JdX+dYQU4Arkpy3jrQ==", 
"company"=>{"name"=>"Agency 8", "legal_name"=>"agency No8 SIA", "reg_number"=>"123456789", "address"=>"street 8", "bank_acc"=>"123456789", "description"=>"Super agency", 
"website"=>"www.google.com"}, "role"=>"seller_buyer", "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"13"}
```

In */common/companies_controller.rb* I have this:

```
def edit
@company = Company.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@company = Company.find(params[:id])
if @company.update_attributes(company_params)
  flash[:success] = "Company updated"
  redirect_to dashboard_path
else
  #render 'edit'
  flash[:error] = "Nothing happened!"
end
end

private
def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, :legal_name, :reg_number,
                            :address, :bank_acc, :currency, :description, :website, :role)
    end
```

In */models/company.rb* I have this:

```
    class Company < ApplicationRecord

#Companies has many users
    has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :accounts
    has_many :user_roles, through: :users, source: :roles

    enum currency: {eur: 1}, _suffix: true
    enum role: {seller_buyer: 1, seller: 2, buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts, :users
```

In view I use this line to select role from drop-down:

```
<option value=<%= f.select :role, Company.roles.keys.to_a, class: 'form-control' %></option>
```

**Update**

This is how view looks like:

```
<div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown">
<%= form_for([:common, @company]) do |f| %>
    <form class="m-t" role="form" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Name"%>
            <%= f.text_field :legal_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Legal name"%>
            <%= f.text_field :reg_number, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Registration number"%>
            <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Address"%>
            <%= f.text_field :bank_acc, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Bank account"%>
            <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Description"%>
            <%= f.text_field :website, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Website"%>
            <select class="form-control m-b" name="role">
            <option value=<%= f.select :role, Company.roles.keys.to_a, class: 'form-control' %></option>
            <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
</form>
```

**What should I change to make "role" enum update/save?**

---

**Update for solution**

This is solution where in Edit action, drop-down shows actual value from database:
`<%= f.select :role, Company.roles.to_a.map { |w| [w[0].humanize, w[0]] }, {}, {class:"form-control m-b"} %>` Other solutions allowed to update, however it did not show current value in Edit action.

Comment: what's the error? did you check the validation result on the model for a clue?

Comment: looks like your parameter is not correct. role should be inside the hash of  company. your view is not right. Check  form `select`.

Comment: No error, it just begins, commits transaction without any value updated in database and then redirects to dashboard_path. I have removed any enum validation from model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5mjLbYZH6tJWOympfEApF2EwbR/Nk4cQFvqtCiXhL3hOIs+yOQGbZUaIFqO42aMyUWr3JdX+dYQU4Arkpy3jrQ==", 
"company"=>{"name"=>"Agency 8", "legal_name"=>"agency No8 SIA", "reg_number"=>"123456789", "address"=>"street 8", "bank_acc"=>"123456789", "description"=>"Super agency", 
"website"=>"www.google.com"}, "role"=>"seller_buyer", "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"13"}
```

Look at the `"role"=>"seller_buyer"` it is out side of `company` hash. It should be like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5mjLbYZH6tJWOympfEApF2EwbR/Nk4cQFvqtCiXhL3hOIs+yOQGbZUaIFqO42aMyUWr3JdX+dYQU4Arkpy3jrQ==", 
    "company"=>{"name"=>"Agency 8", "legal_name"=>"agency No8 SIA", "reg_number"=>"123456789", "address"=>"street 8", "bank_acc"=>"123456789", "description"=>"Super agency", 
    "website"=>"www.google.com", "role"=>"seller_buyer"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"13"}
```

it is happening because your form input is not correctly generated. You should not be use select inside option. `select` will generate options by the given array(`Company.roles.keys.to_a`).

**Edit:**
This should fix your design issue:

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(Company.roles.keys.to_a, class: 'form-control'),{},{class:"form-control m-b"} %>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I removed <option value= .. > and it works now. I will need to figure out how to get those nice drop-downs, but that's another story. Thank you for helping! Rails community the best :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197138/how-to-add-a-class-to-select-tag-in-ruby-on-rails look at the last answer. You can add class in the select and also in the option.

Answer (score 1):

This looks really weird to me.

```
<option value=<%= f.select :role, Company.roles.keys.to_a, class: 'form-control' %></option>
```

You can generate drop-down by simply writing this. You have to add class to the f.select to get the style you need.

```
<%= f.select :role, Company.roles.keys.to_a, {}, class: 'form-control m-b' %>
```

Comment: <option value= .. > is needed for Bootstrap, not related to the error I have. Do you have any idea, why I cannot save enum?

Comment: @matiss  what do you mean by "needed for Bootstrap" ?

Comment: Well, I'm using Inspinia admin theme and as I understand it's how I can get all the styling there. At lease by using <option value= ..> I get nice drop-downs :)

Comment: @matiss You need to add a class ('m-b') to f.select.